# Run Supervisor reload as user

Tags: django, linux, supervisord, capistrano3

I installed Supervisor via...

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

When I deploy my app with Capistrano, I need to run Supervisor as a none root user.

If I run...

```
/usr/bin/supervisorctl reload
```

I get...

```
Permission denied: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py
```

If I run above command with sudo it works fine, but I need to run it without sudo. Is this possible? I tried changing the group and owner of Supervisor to the user running the command, but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you update your question with `/tmp/supervisor.sock` ?

Comment: What about /tmp/supervisor.sock?

Comment: I think it's more of a permission issue that is being caused on `/tmp/supervisor.sock`. By default, the permission of that file is root and it is read only for all other users. Can you check the permissions ?